Svelte 5: How to pass primitives reactivly across components/modules
I have a few dozens of reactive primitive values (like e.g. div_status = "frozen") which I need to pass between component/module boundaries, including +page.svelte files and svelte.js modules. These values represent changable properties of the UI, and will hence influence (a) styles as well as (b) if-else blocks inside some event listeners for user interaction. Importantly, the values need to be reactively on a drag-level, since the UI must respond while the user is dragging (e.g. hovering over a dropzone, dragging for a specific distance, etc.)
Transforming my code base to Svelte 5, I'm not sure, whether to use stores or $state() for this use case.

My problem with stores is, that I don't manage to use them inside the export functions in the svelte.js modules. Furthermore they are hard to refactor.

My problem with using $state() for my primitives (like $state("frozen")) is that I have to complicate things in order not to reassign/overwrite the state: So, to just mutate their values, I would either group multiple primitives together to Object Arrays or blow them up individually (e.g. div_status = {value: "frozen"}).


Lastly, I am confused, whether I should look into how getters/setters work and whether the choice of either stores or $state() depends on my choice of using context-API or just passing them around as props. All in all I'm looking for a solution that is easy to refactor.
Update
I ended up using $state together with getters/setters. For anybody reading this until the official Svelte 5 Docs are out: I very much recommend watching this video of Rich Harris, which explains how to do this, and why it's NOT MORE code to write, even at first glance, you may think so.
I don't use stores any more, but for anybody interested in using them I'll write my code in a separate answer to this question. It will also work in in svelte.js files.

Reassignment of $state is not a problem in itself. Primitives being passed by value prevents updates; this can also be observed in plain JS, e.g.


function createCounter() {
  let value = 0;
  setTimeout(() => value++); // happens later
  
  return value;
}

const counter = createCounter();
console.log('Value copied', counter)
setTimeout(() => console.log('Value copied', counter), 1);



You need to maintain a reference to the value, either via a function or an accessor property.


function createCounter() {
  let value = 0;
  setTimeout(() => value++); // happens later
  
  return () => value;
}

const counter = createCounter();
console.log('Value referenced', counter())
setTimeout(() => console.log('Value referenced', counter()), 1);



Generally one should use runes over stores in Svelte 5; stores are likely to be deprecated in later versions as runes should be able to replace them.
If you have a read-only state, you can return a function as shown in the example above and "receive" that via $derived.by. E.g.
function createCounter() {
    let value = $state(0);
    setTimeout(() => value++); // happens later
    
    return () => value;
}

const counter = $derived.by(createCounter());
$inspect('Counter', counter);

Playground
For write access there are also various options, e.g. using two functions (get/set) or using a { value } box. The box approach is probably the most flexible as it allows the object to be used in things like bind:value={...}.
<script>
    function loggedValue(initial) {
        const state = $state({ value: initial });
        $effect(() => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(state.value));
        });

        return state;
    }

    const count = loggedValue(0);
</script>

<input type=number bind:value={count.value} />

Playground
You can also easily pass such an object into a context; contexts are primarily useful for passing something multiple levels deeper into the component hierarchy. As noted, with props you can directly use a binding on the value to send and receive updates to the value.
Having many primitives that are being passed around might hint at optimization opportunities. Maybe some of them could be grouped and put on a larger $state object with more meaningful property names than "value".
What to use often depends on the exact issue at hand. Sometimes only providing read access to the state and bespoke update functions might be the best approach.

Thank you very much for taking the time for such an in-depth explanation. The first part of your answer was really interesting. Regarding my code decision, I think I really want to go with state (for the reasons you provided), even tough, in the meantime I made it work with stores (see the updated question). To this end, honestly, I don't fully understand, what you mean with a { value } box... do you mean using value as a key like status = $state({value:"frozen"})? An example would really help, since, indeed, I do need write access. Thank you again!

Yes, your example is what I mean by that.

I now have a working test code running with getters/setters and I am pretty happy with it. Wow, it took me quite a while to wrap my head around all of this... not because it's complicated, but because I constantly thought that things will get way too lengthy and complex...... well until I discovered this Video of Rich Harris, telling me that I can wrap status = createSignal("frozen") in utility-functions, which I just write one single time. Awesome!

This video is very outdated, there used to be a time when $state({ value:"frozen" }) would not react to value updates, now this just works due to proxies. You don't need manual getters and setters if the thing in $state is already an object. You should be able to just pass that around and modify the property. If you have any issues with that, ideally ask a separate question and show the non-working code so it can be corrected.

One last question: At 08:39 Rich Harris says that Svelte 5, once in final release, will provide us with opinionated patterns on how to do deal with Signals (maybe even with an import {...} from "svelte/...". Do you know whether there's already an update on this? I somehow did not manage to find any.

There is no such thing. Proxied state, which was added later, already makes this very easy as mentioned, no real for a utility function just $state({ value: ... }). Also classes have been augmented with the ability to add state to them if you initialize a property with $state, e.g. class Box { value = $state() }.

Added a very simple example showing a $state box.

Oh, thanks for pointing to this! I'll update my question once again later, in order not to mislead other people. I got it running the same way as you suggested, however dropping the utility function completely. Is there a reason, why you wrapped everything in a loggedValue() function? Other than that, I want to thank you once again. I learnt a lot today!

It's to illustrate a boundary (the function) and having additional functionality operating on the state (the logging).

As mentioned in the Update in my question above, here's my code for using stores across components/modules boundaries. Maybe it helps someone.
stores.js
export let simpleStore = writable(1);
export let comboStore = writable({a:1});

helpers.svelte.js
import { simpleStore, comboStore } from '$lib/stores.js'

export function handleIncrease() {
    simpleStore.update(value => value + 1);

    comboStore.update(value => {
        return { ...value, a: value.a + 1 };
    });

}

+page.svelte
<script>
import { simpleStore, comboStore } from '$lib/stores.js'
</script>

<p>{$simpleStore}</p>
<p>{$comboStore.a}</p>
<button onclick={handleIncrease}>Increase a</button>

